# React - Default state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I have a question for you about React.

I'd like to know why my code isn't working correctly :

```
const DEFAULT_STATE = {
  disabledItems: [],
  wordToGuess: mots[Math.floor(Math.random() * mots.length)],
  mistakes: 0,
  lose: false,
  win: false,
}

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = { ...DEFAULT_STATE }
  }

  //Arrow function for binding
  //Restart the game
  resetGame = () => {
    this.setState({ ...DEFAULT_STATE })
  }
```

The problem is that my two states disabledItems and wordToGuess are not reset when resetGame is called...

Instead, this the code that is currently working :

```
const DEFAULT_STATE = {
  mistakes: 0,
  lose: false,
  win: false,
}

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      ...DEFAULT_STATE,
      disabledItems: [],
      wordToGuess: mots[Math.floor(Math.random() * mots.length)],
    }
  }

  //Arrow function for binding
  //Restart the game
  resetGame = () => {
    this.setState({
      ...DEFAULT_STATE,
      disabledItems: [],
      wordToGuess: mots[Math.floor(Math.random() * mots.length)],
    })
  }
```

Here, everything do just fine.

Is it a reference problem ? Please help me to understand :) ! Thanks a lot !

Comment: I want to reset my state, go back to the initial state

Answer (score 2):

It is happened because you declare you DEFAULT_STATE object once, and all items stored in memory, and your resetGame only links to this created once object.

But you can make function which will built your state every time.

Example:

```
const buildState = () => ({
  disabledItems: [],
  wordToGuess: mots[Math.floor(Math.random() * mots.length)],
  mistakes: 0,
  lose: false,
  win: false,
});

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = { ...buildState() }
  }

  //Arrow function for binding
  //Restart the game
  resetGame = () => {
    this.setState({ ...buildState() })
  }
```

After that each call `buildState()` returns new different object.

Comment: Thanks that's what I thought but I couldn't really explain why and how. Is there any performance issue with this method ?

Comment: I think it is have not perf issues because, you need to generate new object each time in `resetGame` method whatever.
Or in future you can attach new keys to this object like this: `this.setState({ ...buildState(), foo: 1, bar: 'foo' })`

Comment: OK thanks a lot ! And another (and the last) question :) ! Why do my object keeps the reference ? I'm using : this.state = { ...DEFAULT_STATE } - isn't it a real clone ? It shouldn't links to DEFAULT_STATE, am I wrong ?

Comment: This is because the spread operator only makes a shallow clone. Meaning nested non-primitives are not cloned (AKA your arrays). Generally you don't need deep clones and it's more efficient to do a shallow, but in this case you do need to re-create those nested objects

Comment: It’s links to DEFAULT_STATE but it declared once in your bundle and resetGame method grab it old object

Comment: My state wordToGuess is not reset too, so mots[Math.floor(Math.random() * mots.length)], meaning value generated with function also aren't primitives ?

Comment: Yes, you need to declare DEFAULT STATE as function, because your resetGame must set new wordToGuess to your state all time.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue here is the `wordToGuess` part. 
When you first declare

```
const DEFAULT_STATE = {
  disabledItems: [],
  wordToGuess: mots[Math.floor(Math.random() * mots.length)],
  mistakes: 0,
  lose: false,
  win: false,
}
```

The part `mots[Math.floor(Math.random() * mots.length)]` gets executed and assigns a value to `wordToGuess`, which the becomes constant thought the process.

When you are doing

```
 this.setState({
  ...DEFAULT_STATE,
  disabledItems: [],
  wordToGuess: mots[Math.floor(Math.random() * mots.length)],
})
```

you are recomputing wordToGuess and re-assigning it. I don't think there should be any problem with disabledItems.

So this should also work

```
this.setState({
  ...DEFAULT_STATE,
  wordToGuess: mots[Math.floor(Math.random() * mots.length)],
})
```

Comment: Hi ! In fact, disabledItems isn't reset, same as wordToGuess, that's why I wrote it this way.

Comment: See this example https://jsfiddle.net/fhL0cu7p/ and see if it is any different from your scenario

Comment: Thanks for sharing :) !

Answer (score 0):

Update :

I did something better thanks to roxxypoxxy and it works :

```
const DEFAULT_STATE = {
  disabledItems: [],
  mistakes: 0,
  lose: false,
  win: false,
}

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      ...DEFAULT_STATE,
      wordToGuess: mots[Math.floor(Math.random() * mots.length)],
    }
  }

  //Arrow function for binding
  //Restart the game
  resetGame = () => {
    this.setState({
      ...DEFAULT_STATE,
      wordToGuess: mots[Math.floor(Math.random() * mots.length)],
    })
  }
```

The problem was in my way to add something in disabledItems. I was doing this :

```
const disabledItems = this.state.disabledItems
disabledItems.push(letter)
this.setState({ disabledItems })
```

Instead of doing that :

```
this.setState({
  disabledItems: [...this.state.disabledItems, letter],
})
```